# Does word order matter when using names?

Tags: word-order, names

Does word order matter when mentioning names?

> - Once I am ready with basic groundwork, I will discuss it with *Travis, Nick and you.*
> - Once I am ready with basic groundwork, I will discuss it with *Travis, you and Nick.*

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically, both of those sentences are perfectly fine. The order of the names doesn't matter with regards to whether or not a sentence is correctly written.

The order of the names might matter, though, depending on the meaning you are trying to convey. If I am going to discuss the groundwork separately with Travis, then with Nick, then with you, I may wish to say as much with the order of the names as in the first sentence (although it's not clearly denoted that that is the case). The order of the names could also connote the perceived importance of the different people or the order in which I thought of them, particularly in conversational English.